# HP server is replaced and RAID 10 started rebuilding

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, raid10

We've server HP Proliant DL360p Gen8 which was recently replaced with HP Proliant DL380p Gen8. Both have same P420i Raid controller. We setup RAID 10 on DL360p, 4x500GB where 1000 GB 1 Logical Drive. We simply inserted these 4 drives in DL380 in right order just like they were in DL360. Server is restarted and started rebuilding its 2nd drive (green, blinking) while number 4 drive is with white DO NOT EJECT option. No drive was faulty, just a server replacement. However it is taking much longer time, about 6 hours have been passed and it is on Windows Logo screen and showing some processing at bottom of screen in circle. We simply let it boot from Windows. So we can't see any progress bar or % completed. Just windows logo screen with circle processing and on Server one disk (#2) is showing it is rebuilding and #4 disk is showing DO NOT EJECT (on caddy side LED). How much time it should take? What if by any reason server shuts down, will it start rebuilding from start or resume the previous rebuild. Can a sudden shutdown (due to electricity/UPS failure) of server during rebuilding can be dangerous?